# replacement for jQuery .closest() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a replacement selector for the [jQuery Closest Selector](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). I noticed that it is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.8. I am currently using it quite a bit in my JavaScript and I am anxious to find out if there is something similar that I could use effectively.

Comment: I don't see any information about it being deprecated or removed. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the link you posted, it mentions `.parents([selector])` - will that not do for your use case?

Comment: It is not being removed...

Comment: @nathanhayfield - It's only for `.closest( selectors [, context ] )`.

Comment: Ah, then you should [link to it properly](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest2). From the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/): *"$(element).closest(Array) returning Array: This was a strange signature of the .closest() method intended for use by the old .live(), but not used by any other code as far as we know. Normal uses of .closest() returning a jQuery object are not affected by this signature being removed."*.

Comment: i'm voting to close this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the `.closest( selectors [, context ] )` method signature was removed.  Everything else is fine!

Answer (score 5):

It's not deprecated. Just the internal method that returns an array. From jQuery Docs:

> This signature (only!) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.8. It was primarily meant to be used internally or by plugin
>   authors.

Btw, this should behave the same as `closest` (on one element):

```
$el.parents( selector ).eq(0)
```